# What are some ways to negotiate with a lawyer to pay off an outstanding debt?

Tags: debt, debt-reduction, debt-collection

I owe around 7000 for an outstanding debt and they are trying to take me to court for it. If I have 4000 now, how can I get them to accept that money to take care of the entire debt amount? I know that the other option would be a payment plan but I would rather take care of it all now if I can.

Comment: Are they taking you to small claims court? What is the maximum that can be levied against you? It may not be that far off $4,000.

Comment: I have been told by a lawyer friend that they will try to freeze my assets

Comment: What kind of debt is it? I think you should take threats seriously, but sometimes lawyers talk more than they act.

Comment: Freeze your assets, garnish your wages... yeah, if you try to duck a legitimate debt, and don't have an exceptionally good reason for not doing so, the court may "help" you find a way to make the payments. Better to see if you can pay more but spread it out enough that you can afford it, while not paying unreasonable interest rates... "refinance" the debt, essentially.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beg, plead, whimper, and hope they take pity on you. Sorry, but there's no way to force someone to take less than you legitimately owe them except to declare bankrupty, and even that may not do it.

If they aren't interested in throwing away $3000, your best bet really is to try to arrange a payment plan, or to get a loan from somewhere and pay that back over time. Of course either of those options is likely to cost you interest, but that's what happens...

I wish I could say something else, but there really isn't any good news here.